# Obj-C message sent to deallocated object (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS), with iOS5, ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I'm developing an iOS5 App using ARC, and I started to get some random EXEC_BAD_ACCESS crashes that I cannot figure out.. By random I mean it is very unpredictable: sometimes it may take a long time to crash, sometimes short. and there is also no one specific button/tablecell/etc. that trigger the crash. Every user interaction can possibly crash the app, but you cannot repeat the crash.

I have tried to turn on NSZombie and also some malloc debugger tools. In Instruments the crash error reads: An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x10bd1b40. And the last part of the reference count log looks like this:

```
475 CoursesFirstViewController  Release 2   02:23.253.631   0   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
476 CoursesFirstViewController  Release 1   02:23.253.838   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
477 CoursesFirstViewController  Zombie  -1  02:35.752.420   0   Foundation  objectHash
```

The 2, 1, -1 thing are the reference counts. I have no idea why it skips 0 and drop to -1, crashing the program (all entries but the last have continuous ref counts). Also I have no idea what objectHash is.

My app comprises of multiple functions, accessible as icons on my main screen. CoursesFirstViewController is one of the functions. Always, it is CoursesFirstViewController and objectHash that crash the app, even if I am at somewhere else. (This is the case for the log above: I went out of CoursesFirstViewController (thus returning to the main screen of my app) at 02:23, but after 12 sec, when I was in some other function, the app crashed) I only need to enter CourseFirstViewController, mess around with it for a bit, and then go elsewhere to continue using the app, and after a while it will just crash.

I'm really mad of this problem now. I have searched SO and Google for quite a while but cannot find a solution. Any help will be greatly greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you managed to get a stack trace for a few occurrences, or it's the only one you have?

Comment: @zneak sorry what is a stack trace? is it NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]); ?
 every time the last several lines of the crash log look like the above.

Comment: In Instruments, choose `View > Extended Detail` from the menu bar.  Then when you click on an event in the reference count log, the extended detail view will show you the call stack (stack track) at the time of the event.

Comment: @robmayoff yea I already checked that but didn't see anything especially useful there. the last few calls are objectHash, hashProbe, [NSConcreteHashTable rehashAround], [NSConcreteHashTable removeItem] etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @robmayoff yea I already checked that but didn't see anything especially useful there. the last few calls are objectHash, hashProbe, [NSConcreteHashTable rehashAround], [NSConcreteHashTable removeItem] etc.

This is actually somewhat useful. This is telling us that a collection, probably an `NSDictionary`, but possibly an `NSSet` is being destroyed. From your earlier information it seems to be an autoreleased collection that is created during the nib instantiation process (so probably an ivar of `CoursesFirstViewController`). That's where I'd be looking anyway given the symptoms, but the crash seems to confirm it.

General recommendations are auditing any `__bridge` casts or `unsafe_unretained` properties.

Another hunch is that you've named a method in a way that violates Cocoa memory management. The most likely misnaming would be that you have a property that starts with `new` or `copy`. This would definitely be an issue if you have ARC code call misnamed non-ARC code.

Comment: I'm now 80% certain that it's the searching function that is causing trouble, although I haven't figured out exactly how. I will take a look at the searchResults collections to see if anything is wrong with them. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Rob, it was some NSDictionary that was causing me trouble. I didn't figure out exactly what's wrong with it, but I rewrote the searching function and now everything is fine. Appreciated!

Comment: Holy cow. We had a Core Data property named "newRequirements". It worked great until we used XCode5 to build. Then we were getting zombies all over the place. Renaming the CoreData model attribute to "nextRequirements" sorted it. Took about 6 hours to spot and fix that one. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of your properties is marked "weak" when it should be "strong" and is going out of scope and getting released before you access it. ARC can't save you in that case and you will get the above random crash behavior.

If you don't have any luck finding it I would resort to doing a global search for "weak" properties on your project and double-check each one to make sure it isn't something you expect to hang around. It's tedious but honestly doesn't take that long to do and sometimes turns up more than the one bug.

Comment: A property marked `weak` is set to nil when the object is deallocated, so you shouldn't see a zombie message in that case.  A property marked `assign` or `unsafe_unretained` could point to a zombie though.

Comment: Actually ARC does prevent the crash in this situation, because it zeroes out weak referring pointers on deallocation.

Comment: I think everything related to my CoursesFirstViewController is strong. Only some IBOutlets that Xcode creates are weak, and they are all in some other functions so shouldn't be the cause. (If I don't access CFVC at least once then everything seems to be fine.)

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your Instruments output that the zombie object is of type `CoursesFirstViewController`.  We often use a view controller as the delegate for some other object, and most objects that have delegates do not retain their delegates.

I am assuming that you aren't using any `unsafe_unretained` properties or variables, or any `retain`-type properties.  So I assume that none of your objects is keeping a dangling reference to the `CoursesFirstViewController` zombie.

Since the system libraries have to work with non-ARC code, they do not use ARC's weak references.  So if some system object has a `CoursesFirstViewController` as its delegate, and the `CoursesFirstViewController` is destroyed but the system object is not, then the system object is left with a dangling reference to the destroyed object.

So, check whether you're using the `CoursesFirstViewController` as the delegate for any system objects.  If so, are you sure those objects don't outlive the `CoursesFirstViewController`?

Comment: I'm using `CoursesFirstViewController` as `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate`. But I think as these are components of the UI of the view controller, they shouldn't outlive `CoursesFirstViewController`? The only other thing is I'm using `ASIHttpRequest` which isn't using ARC, and I have some local `ASIHTTPRequest` variables whose delegates are set to `CoursesFirstViewController`. But I'm also using `ASIHTTPRequest` elsewhere in my program and they seem to be fine, so I'm not so sure about this..

Comment: Typically the UI elements in a view controller's view hierarchy are destroyed by the time the view controller is destroyed.  But it's possible that you are keeping a reference to one of them.  (You should know whether you are.)  I'm not familiar with `ASIHttpRequest` so I would certainly suggest investigating whether those objects can outline the view controller.  Does an `ASIHttpRequest` spawn a thread, or register for some asynchronous notification of network activity?  That would be likely to retain the `ASIHttpRequest`, letting it outlive the view controller.

Comment: I have just modified `ASIHTTPRequest` objects so that they no longer have `CoursesFirstViewController` as their delegate. Yet the crash persists.. But I also don't think the search display controller or the search bar can somehow overlive `CoursesFirstViewController`... :(